# replacing column field separator using sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file `1.txt:`

```
cam:45c62741b9c99e1dcf3c140e8e3df635::dv:johnybold@yahoo.com:83.228.32.24
gamer:3dabd5bd7984b0286eba52d4a7db2dea:$Wm?1Z3MPErXl7%yk^Pc#%iu\9LFc{:octopus@vida.tv:93.182.154.63
:adc0a54f8d21694848200ae043fa99f2:GqJ:LOLPELIC@trash-mail.com:84.176.127.30
! Aa:da99417e29ab0aa67f97db64f091836b:k_P:prus_da@yahoo.com:82.179.236.154
```

I want to change the column separator (currently it is ':') to '||o||'.
I want to change only the 1st, 3rd and 4th column separator as 2nd column contains something like `hash:salt`.

The script I am trying is:

```
sed 's/:/||o||/1;s/:/||o||/2;s/:/||o||/2' 1.txt
```

The only problem is in the results where ':' is included in the salt.
The output I am getting is:

```
cam||o||45c62741b9c99e1dcf3c140e8e3df635:||o||dv||o||johnybold@yahoo.com:83.228.32.24
gamer||o||3dabd5bd7984b0286eba52d4a7db2dea:$Wm?1Z3MPErXl7%yk^Pc#%iu\9LFc{||o||octopus@vida.tv||o||93.182.154.63
||o||adc0a54f8d21694848200ae043fa99f2:GqJ||o||LOLPELIC@trash-mail.com||o||84.176.127.30
! Aa||o||da99417e29ab0aa67f97db64f091836b:k_P||o||prus_da@yahoo.com||o||82.179.236.154
```

The first line of the output is wrong.

```
Expected output :
cam||o||45c62741b9c99e1dcf3c140e8e3df635::dv||o||johnybold@yahoo.com||o||83.228.32.24
```

Rest of the output is correct.

What I am expecting is replace first ':' from forward and second and third time the replacement should be from backwards, so that ':' in the salt gets ignored.

Comment: Why is the third row missing the first column, and why does the last row contain spaces and `!` in the first column? Was this the plan?

Comment: The data is like that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?:^[^:]*\K:)|(:(?=[^:]+:?[^:]+$))
```

Basic idea:

- Either get the first `:` that occurs in the line
- Or `:` that is followed by at most one other `:`

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/X7cvI0/1)

Demo with substitution: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/X7cvI0/2)

How to run it with `perl`:

```
perl -p -e 's/(?:^[^:]*\K:)|(:(?=[^:]+:?[^:]+$))/||o||/g' input.txt
```

Comment: I tried sed 's/(?:^[^:]*\K:)|(:(?=[^:]+:?[^:]+$))/||o||/' 1.txt, but it is not working.

Comment: Use `sed -r 's/...` to have extended regex available.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin doesn't seem to support `\K`. Afair it also does not support variable-length lookbehinds, so essentially OP is out of luck with sed. Perl has full PCRE.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla Yeah, that's because `sed` doesn't support `\K`, unfortunately. Using perl here is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Short **`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's/:+/||o||/3g; s/:/||o||/' file
```

The output:

```
cam||o||45c62741b9c99e1dcf3c140e8e3df635::dv||o||johnybold@yahoo.com||o||83.228.32.24
gamer||o||3dabd5bd7984b0286eba52d4a7db2dea:$Wm?1Z3MPErXl7%yk^Pc#%iu\9LFc{||o||octopus@vida.tv||o||93.182.154.63
||o||adc0a54f8d21694848200ae043fa99f2:GqJ||o||LOLPELIC@trash-mail.com||o||84.176.127.30
! Aa||o||da99417e29ab0aa67f97db64f091836b:k_P||o||prus_da@yahoo.com||o||82.179.236.154
```

Comment: Sorry for upvote/unupvote. Could you explain whether it works for any number of junk-':' in the `hash:salt`-section, or does it work only under the assumption that there will be one contiguous block of ':'s? It seems to do strange things if the `salt` part contains more ':' that are not in the beginning.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, those nuances should have been mentioned in your question. At the moment, this approach works for your current input. What if some hash would be `asd::sasd:asd:asd23:::3f3f4:345f:::234f:` ?

Comment: It's not my question, I just wanted to upvote your solution because it was shorter and probably more efficient. But I fear that it could succeed on provided test data, and then fail when applied to the actual data... But yeah, that's just a wild speculation about just how broken OP's actual data might be, it's not clear from the question. Good hint with `/3g;` anyway.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I just missed that that wasn't a question from the OP. I've missed that in confusion (automatically)

Comment: I am getting following error:  sed: 1: "s/:+/||o||/3g; s/:/||o||/": more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags